# Is it possible to colorize permissions-part of the output of `ls`?

Tags: command-line, colors

In the `rwx` permissions that are listed by `ls -l`, is it possible to put the first set of rwx in red, the next in blue and the third in green?

For example, is the following possible:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Arbitrary Command Output Colourer](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/acoc.shtml). It can, well, colourize arbitrary command outputs. There is no working DEB archive, but installation trivial (once you have `ruby` installed). Configuration is via regular expressions and can do whas you want.

Comment: Super! And in Ruby too!

Answer (score 3):

[Parsing `ls` output is notoriously error prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but here's a working version based on `find`:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -d '' perms name
do
    echo "${perms:0:1}$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)${perms:1:3}$(tput setaf 4)${perms:4:3}$(tput setaf 2)${perms:7:3}$(tput sgr0) ${name}"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%M\t%f\0")
```